# How to make 'Authorize Attribute' Role and Permission

Tags: model-view-controller

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
[MyAuthorization(Roles="ADMIN", Permissions="USER_ADD")]
public ActionResult Add()

[MyAuthorization(Roles="ADMIN", Permissions="USER_EDIT")]
public ActionResult Edit()

[MyAuthorization(Roles="ADMIN", Permissions="USER_DELETE")]
public ActionResult Delete()
}
```

My custom tables :

```
[ Permission { ID, Name } ] // Get_User, Delete_User vb.vb.

[ User_Permission { ID, UserID, RoleID, PermissionID } ]  // 1 - John - Admin - Get_User
```

How do I make 'Authorize Attribute' Role and Permission?

```
AuthorizeCore Method in AuthorizeAttribute Class is override...

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
    if(user has any permission of Permissions)
        return true;  //  **I'm stuck in this section**
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to indent your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Comment: have a look at and upvote if it helps you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192296/roles-in-authorize-attribute-does-not-work-as-expected-in-mvc-4